# Which microphone is usefull to replace the original MEMS Microphon of iRig Accoustic Stage?

Tags: microphones, wiring

Yesterday I broke the wire of my iRig Acoustic Stage pickup. The wire is very thin (in my own opinion an absolute cheek). On the internet or at the music store, there was no way to buy the microphone itself. I do not want to pay 100 Euro again, to buy a new Acoustic Stage set.

Does someone have an idea, whether and which other microphone can be used? I strongly believe an other clipable mono mini microphone can be used, but I have no clue about the influence about the sound??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you won't be able to use a different kind of microphone with the iRig. It uses a specific type of microphone, the [MEMS](https://www.edn.com/design/analog/4430264/Basic-principles-of-MEMS-microphones-).

EDIT: I should say that it is UNLIKELY that you can use a different kind of microphone. It is possible that they have a processing unit built into the mic itself that outputs normal voltage based signal. The manufacturer's information suggests otherwise but I didn't see anything that says that it is exclusive to that mic. You could test the unit with a cheap Piezo stick-on and see if it works...

The manufacturer sells a replacement mic for the product directly:

[iRig Acoustic Stage MEMS Microphone](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/shop/?start=0&ipp=48&cat4=spareparts)